# What kind of policy evaluation and policy improvement AlphaGo, AlphaGo Zero and AlphaZero are using

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients, alphazero

I'm trying to find out what kind of policy improvement and policy evaluation AlphaGo, AlphaGo Zero, and AlphaZero are using. By looking into their respective paper and SI, I can conclude that it is a kind of policy gradient actor-critic approach, where the policy is evaluated by a critic and is improved by and actor. Yet still can't fit it to any of the known policy gradient algorithms.